Cannot run PySide6 application: unable to load Shiboken DLL
Good afternoon.
I faced the following problem:
I wrote a (PySide6) application, built it into an exe and tried to run it on Windows7, but I failed. After analyzing the logs and googling it turned out that the problem is in the python version - I was writing in python 3.12, and Windows 7 supports 3.8 at most. I downloaded the aforementioned version and decided to redo the project (venv was already created for this version of python). So far I just copied all the necessary files, installed the Pyside6 library and tried to run the application, but got an exception:
PySide6/__init__.py: Unable to import Shiboken from D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper, D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm_display, C:\Users\xeniy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.zip, C:\Users\xeniy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs, C:\Users\xeniy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib, C:\Users\xeniy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38, D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper\.venv, D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper\.venv\lib\site-packages, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm_plotly_backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
  File "D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper\.venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper\.venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 64, in _setupQtDirectories
    from shiboken6 import Shiboken
  File "D:\FinanceHelper\FinanceHelper\.venv\lib\site-packages\shiboken6\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from shiboken6.Shiboken import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing Shiboken: Не найдена указанная процедура.

This is my shiboken6 folder content:

How to solve this problem? I need the application for Windows 7.
I tried reinstalling the libraries - it didn't help. I even tried installing libraries of older versions:
 pip install PySide6==6.6.3 shiboken6==6.6.3 pyside6-addons==6.6.3 pyside6-essentials==6.6.3
Collecting PySide6==6.6.3
  Obtaining dependency information for PySide6==6.6.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/a2/5e70cfd298c33f9d7a658086367999306c09d99eb75b0ad2e042fdc84279/PySide6-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached PySide6-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.5 kB)
Collecting shiboken6==6.6.3
  Obtaining dependency information for shiboken6==6.6.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/06/4f409d6f241f276ac3233023de12d34367af9cfb1bab76bbbdefa8da8182/shiboken6-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached shiboken6-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting pyside6-addons==6.6.3
  Obtaining dependency information for pyside6-addons==6.6.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/46/1c9e3d93c412f5f712a0c530f128346a1b9cb1e2c6d71040cf8d70a13955/PySide6_Addons-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached PySide6_Addons-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting pyside6-essentials==6.6.3
  Obtaining dependency information for pyside6-essentials==6.6.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/5e/84f70f643a9d4de4e302dad3906181ca6c186fed2cf432b22f04869bf290/PySide6_Essentials-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached PySide6_Essentials-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Using cached PySide6-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (520 kB)
Using cached shiboken6-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
Using cached PySide6_Addons-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (104.1 MB)
Using cached PySide6_Essentials-6.6.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (75.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: shiboken6, pyside6-essentials, pyside6-addons, PySide6
Successfully installed PySide6-6.6.3 pyside6-addons-6.6.3 pyside6-essentials-6.6.3 shiboken6-6.6.3


That didn't work either.

Unfortunately Qt 6.x itself was designed for Windows 10 and above. Refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows.html

it's strange - now I work in Windows 10, and it's don't install.
